# JCombobox How to use model?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying to use Model which I set in Window Builder.

```
 'comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"}));'
```

I Don't know how to use this text "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" in my If statment. 
There is full code.

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Easy",
                "Medium", "Hard" }));
        comboBox.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        comboBox.setBounds(101, 67, 194, 39);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    Snake.dificaulty = 1; // this variable is telling about difficulty level
            }

        });
```

Comment: My warning against WindowBuilder; it generates code that you do not understand. If you have code that you don't understand, problems like this are sure to arise.

Comment: Define your `comboBox` as final. When you can acces it from ItemListener and can get value in many ways: index of selected item `comboBox.getSelectedIndex()`(in your case 0 - Easy, 1 - Medium...); or you can use text value like `comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like:

```
String item = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

You can then use this in the ItemListener. If you are doing something complicated, write another method that does the complex stuff then call it from the `itemStateChanged()` method, passing the `ItemEvent` variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ItemListener` you can access the source of the event. Then you can access any property of the combo box.

```
JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
String item = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

No need to make the combo box final.